# How to find $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \sqrt[n]{ \int_0^1 |f(x)|^{n} dx } $?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

How to find $\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty }  \sqrt[n]{ \int_0^1 |f(x)|^{n} dx } $ , where $f(x)$ is a continuous real function on $[0,1]$?